# Can I ask a question about making a kitchen garden on my balcony?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask this sort of question on the main site given the dimensions of the balcony?

Comment: I think that would still be kinda vague. We'd do more of the plant-recommendations or variety-selection for existing systems, more than the construction aspect, please read http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more detail. If you have the beds/planters constructed, we will help with layout/planning too.

Comment: @J.Musser actually I am also referring to plant selection thing. I don't have any beds but I am willing to get big flower pots.

Comment: Yes, then, we do have a plant-recommendations tag, and a variety-selection tag. Those are topics we cover. You need to provide as uch detail as possible for best answers. Like where you are located, how much light is available, etc.

Comment: Actually  I am more concerned about the size of the flower pot and kind of vegetable or plant that can be grown in such tight space. Will that be okay?

Comment: That should be on-topic! Just be sure to search the q/as we already have, in case something already answered you. :)

Comment: Try this question for a start, then ask for more details as you need them: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/plants-that-can-be-grown-in-usda-zone-8a

Comment: There are lots of questions about houseplants, plants in containers outside, and I've seen recent questions about plants on a deck and/or balcony.